# Comparar inteiro e ponteiro

Tags: c, linux, arquivo, int, matriz

Boas, tenho uma questão, eu estou a tentar copiar uma linha para um ficheiro mas aparece um erro que diz que não posso comparar um integer com um pointer, alguem consegue me ajudar?
O erro está na linha `ch = getc(file1);` e `while(ch != EOF)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define GetCurrentDir getcwd  //get the path of file
#define BUFFER_LEN 1024


int main(){

    char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];  //get   
    char line[BUFFER_LEN];  //get command line   
    char* argv[100];        //user command   
    char* path= "/bin/";    //set path at bin   
    char *ch;
    char progpath[20];      //full file path
    int argc;               //arg count  
    FILE *file1, *file2;    //Files for history 
    int delete_line, count=0;   //line to delete and counter



while(1){


    file1 = fopen("fileOne","w");
    if(GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath)))
    {
        printf("%s",cCurrentPath);   
    }
    printf("/SimpleShell>> ");                    //print shell prompt

    if(!fgets(line, BUFFER_LEN, stdin))
    {                       //get command and put it in line 
        break;                                //if user hits CTRL+D break
    }
    else if(line, BUFFER_LEN, SIGQUIT){
            fopen("fileOne.c","r");
        ch = getc(file1);
        while(ch != EOF){   
            printf("%s",ch);
        } 
    } 

    if(count<20)
    {
        fputs(argv[100] ,file1);  
    }
    else{
        fclose(file1);
        file1 = fopen("fileOne.c","r"); 
        rewind(file1);        
        file2 = fopen("repicla.c","w"); 
        ch = getc(file1);   
        while(ch != EOF){       
            ch = getc(file1);       
            if(ch != "\n"){         
                count++;            
                if(count != 20){                
                putc(ch, file2);            
                }
            }   
        }   
        fclose(file1);  
        fclose(file2);  
        remove("fileOne.c");    
        rename("replica.c","fileOne.c");    
        fputs(argv[100] ,file1);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`getc()` retorna um `int`, não um `char *`. Neste `int` está o valor ASCII do próximo caracter no ficheiro. E, realmente, quando dizes `while (ch != EOF)`, estás a comparar o valor desse caracter com o valor `EOF` que marca o fim do ficheiro, isto é, já não há mais caracteres a recuperar.

Então deves declarar `ch` como `int`, não `char *`. Assim teu programa deve funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado, percebi a explicação mas mesmo assim esta linha de código dá o mesmo erro if(ch != '\n')

Comment: No código, está `if (ch!="\n")`; nota as aspas duplas, não simples. Isso faz com que `"\n"` seja do tipo `const char []`, então ele está tentando comparar `int` com `char *`.